# How to set Outlook contact "Notes" Property from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-interop

I need to programatically Insert a contact to outlook Contact using C# application.
I am using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem Object.

I am able to set name, email, phone, etc. However, it does not seem to have a property for "NOTES"

How can I set the notes for the outlook contact?

Here is the code I am using:

```
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application outlookObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder fldContacts = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder)outlookObj.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem newContact = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem)fldContacts.Items.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olContactItem);

        newContact.FullName ="Whatever Name";
        newContact.Email1Address = "Email@domain.com";

       //no property for newContact.Notes :(

        newContact.Save();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I recall, you want `newContact.Body`

Answer (score 2):

Outlook saves Notes as Body while saving contact

```
string  Notes = newContact.Body;
```